# Travelling from one schengen country to another

Tags: visas, schengen, schengen-visas, luxembourg

I am an Indian student who recently finished his masters from France and is about to start his PhD in Luxembourg from December. Currently, I have applied for a tourist visa to Luxembourg for 5 days in October to visit my new workplace and have provided the itinerary likewise. However, after applying I have decided to visit my old uni and professors in France and stay there for about a month, after my Luxembourg visit.

My questions are:

1) since most probably the Luxembourg tourist visa will be issued as "duration of stay: 5days" do I need to apply for a separate French visa for the vacation afterwards?

2) in case I apply and get the French visa, will it be an issue that I won't be returning to India from Luxembourg, as I had mentioned and shown tickets while applying?
I will be obliged if someone can help me out .

Comment: are you still in france, or are you back in India already? If you are still (legally) in France you should be able to travel to Luxembourg for a visit without any sort of formality

Comment: No am in India and my visa for France expired a week ago. Thats why all the hassle.

Answer (score 1):

1. Even if your Luxembourg visa includes the 15-day "period of grace" contemplated by the [Schengen Visa Code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02009R0810-20160412) in Article 24, the visa will not be sufficient for an additional 1-month stay in France.  It would, however, be within the rules for you to stay in France for a week or two.  There is however no guarantee that they will include a grace period.

   For a one-month additional stay, therefore, you will definitely require another visa.
2. There should be no problem with your change in plans from the original Luxembourg visa application.  Problems that *could* arise in such a case include:

   - *Your new itinerary causes you to exceed 90 days presence in a 180-day period.*  That is not the case here.
   - *Your new itinerary implies that your first application was fraudulent.*  It is unlikely that anyone would reach this conclusion.  Such changes are usually made without disclosing them to the authorities, but you are disclosing them.  Furthermore, as someone who is between two periods of authorized long-term presence in the two countries, you are not likely to be seen as someone with a motive to overstay or to submit fraudulent visa application.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. One further question I have is, will it be an issue if there is no stamp on my Luxembourg visa by border control while leaving the country? As I will travel to France by train most probably.

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem if you have no visa stamp since nobody would expect it to be done.  But you might want to keep your validated train ticket, so you're able to prove your departure date if necessary.